# Bouncing ball code causes jitter in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-physics, easeljs, matter.js

I have a HTML Canvas on my website that I use to contain balls that drop into the canvas, they bounce around and have a real good time settling down at the bottom in a range of ways.

I was under the impression this was working perfectly. However, it has now been brought to my attention these balls jitter and freak out on other people's computers. I checked the browser they are using and it is the same as mine (Chrome V79). So just to clarify - I have never had it bug on my computer but it consistently has this jitter on other peoples computers, some with more powerful computers as well as lower spec computers.

This is it (this CodePen doesn't have the jitter on their computers, so you may not see it also): https://codepen.io/jason-is-my-name/pen/gObKGRg

This is a video of the bug: https://streamable.com/vtg0g

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true
    });
    $.when(
        $.getScript("https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js"),
        $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.10.0/matter.min.js"),
        $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        })
    ).done(function () {
        new App();
    });
});

function App() {
    var self = this;

    self.running = false;
    self.initialized = false;
    var stageClicked = false;
    var stage, canvas;

    var canvasWidth = 410;
    var canvasHeight = 550;
    var ballBounce = 0.8;
    var balls = [];
    var matterJsBalls = [];
    var _gravityY = 1;
    var _gravityX = 0;
    var FPS = 60;
    var infoText, detailsText;
    var ballsInitalized = false;
    var iOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/);
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    var engine = Matter.Engine.create();

    var world = engine.world;

    var floor = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight + 50, canvasWidth, 100, {
        isStatic: true,
        render: {
            visible: false
        }
    });
    var leftWall = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(-50, canvasHeight / 2, 100, canvasHeight, {
        isStatic: true,
        render: {
            visible: false
        }
    });
    var rightWall = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(canvasWidth + 50, canvasHeight / 2, 100, canvasHeight, {
        isStatic: true,
        render: {
            visible: false
        }
    });

    Matter.World.add(world, [floor, leftWall, rightWall]);

    self.initialize = function () {
        toggleListeners(true);
        self.initCanvas();
        self.initGame();
    };

    var toggleListeners = function (enable) {
        if (!enable) return;
    };

    self.refresh = function () {};

    self.initCanvas = function () {
        canvas = $("#ball-stage").get(0);
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

        window.addEventListener("resize", onStageResize, false);
        onStageResize();
        createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
        createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(FPS);

        self.initialized = true;
    };

    self.initGame = function () {
        initBalls(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    };

    var onStageResize = function () {
        stage.canvas.width = canvasWidth;
        stage.canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    };

    var initBalls = function (stageX, stageY) {
        var imagesArray = [
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
    "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg",
   "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-320-80.jpg"
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
            (function (imageArray) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    var arrayImage = new Image();

                    arrayImage.onload = function () {
                        addBall(arrayImage, stageX / 2, 52);
                    };

                    arrayImage.src = imageArray;
                }, (i * 1000) + 1000);
            })(imagesArray[i]);
        }
    };

    var addBall = function (img, x, y) {
        var shape = new createjs.Shape();
        shape.id = balls.length;
        shape.radius = 51.25;
        shape.mass = shape.radius;
        shape.x = x;
        shape.y = y;
        shape.vx = rand(-3, 3);
        shape.vy = rand(-3, 3);
        shape.stuck = false;

        var transform = new createjs.Matrix2D();
        transform.appendTransform(-shape.radius, -shape.radius, 1, 1, 0);
        shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(img, "repeat", transform).drawCircle(0, 0, shape.radius);

        stage.addChild(shape);
        balls.push(shape);

        var circle = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, shape.radius, {
            isStatic: false,
            restitution: ballBounce
        });

        Matter.World.add(world, circle);

        Matter.Body.applyForce(circle, {
            x: circle.position.x,
            y: circle.position.y
        }, {
            x: shape.vx * 0.05,
            y: shape.vy * 0.05
        });

        matterJsBalls.push(circle);
    };

    var tick = function () {
        Matter.Engine.update(engine, 16);
        for (var i = 0; i < matterJsBalls.length; i++) {
            var curBall = balls[i];
            var curMatterJsBall = matterJsBalls[i];
            curBall.x = curMatterJsBall.position.x;
            curBall.y = curMatterJsBall.position.y;
        }
        stage.update();
    };

    var rand = function (min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        return Math.random() * max + min;
    };

    self.initialize();
    return self;
}

window.log = function f() {
    log.history = log.history || [];
    log.history.push(arguments);
    if (this.console) {
        var args = arguments,
            newarr;
        args.callee = args.callee.caller;
        newarr = [].slice.call(args);

        if (typeof console.log === "object")
            log.apply.call(console.log, console, newarr);
        else console.log.apply(console, newarr);
    }
};
(function (a) {
    function b() {}

    for (
        var c = "assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(
                ","
            ),
            d; !!(d = c.pop());

    ) {
        a[d] = a[d] || b;
    }
})(
    (function () {
        try {
            console.log();
            return window.console;
        } catch (a) {
            return (window.console = {});
        }
    })()
);
```

```css
.tech-stack-icons-container{width:410px;height:100%}#ball-stage{width:100%;height:100%;background-color:pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tech-stack-icons-container">
    <canvas id="ball-stage"></canvas>
</div>
```

How can I find a fix to this invisible issue?

Comment: It runs perfectly for me. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` (works on my machine TM)

Comment: This is not related to the canvas, rather a problem with how you use matter,js. As the bug is non reproducible there is no way to determine a fix. I would guess that you check if a new ball is clear (not overlapping other balls) before you add it to the sim. Overlapping balls will give each ball a huge kick of energy which will result in "jitter" similar to what you see.

Comment: The time difference between ball creation and strength of gravity means the balls will always have fallen below the ball creation area. I am not sure this is the reason for the jitter.

Comment: can you provide code which used in that video because current code works fine for me... so cannot give solution on your problem

Comment: This is the problem buddy. It is a direct copy...

Comment: Likely something else in your html, css or js markup causing the issue

Comment: Hi Jason. Please do not (re)add signatures to your posts - profile card are though to be sufficient for authorship purposes here. I believe this is covered in the help pages and/or Meta site. We tend to discourage [home-made tags in the title too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495) - either make them an organic part of the title, or just use the tag system.